How to use semgrep to detect the fixed salt of pbkdf2_hmac()?
I have the code sample as below:
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac


def getHash(password):
    '''
    create a hash of the password with a salt.
    '''
    salt = b'my_salt'
    hash = pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', password, salt, 100000)
    return hash

I have tried with the pattern pbkdf2_hmac($ALGO, $PASS, '$SALT', $ITER) but '$SALT' only works when salt is a string like salt='my_salt'.
